# PDO configuration windows authentication

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to configure PDO with windows authentication.

I wrote the following code:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlsrv:server='.$config['db']['db_host'] .';Database='. $config['db']['db_name'], NULL, NULL);
```

It doesn't work. 
I received this error:

> This extension requires either the
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client, the Microsoft SQL Server 2008
>   Native Client or the Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Native Client to
>   communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712'

In my php.ini I have:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll 
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

Do you know if I use a particular library or configuration in php.ini?

Comment: Have you tried installing Microsoft SQL Server Native Client?

Comment: Yes, I did it!!!!